# Events to communicate between game objects in a component based system?

Tags: architecture

I am planning to try and implement a small simple "game engine" thing, with game objects that have their components and all that. My problem is, how do they communicate with one another?

I understand event based communication is popular, but how does it work practically?
Let's say I make a platformer shooter, and the player needs to know about every platform, enemy, bullet, every frame. How will the events look? I thought the player should just say "hey scene manager, I need to know about the platforms. any chance you give me a pointer to those?" and then the player can just handle it. But generally, the address of the platforms (or any other game object) shouldn't change that much, so I am back to a situation where everyone knows about everyone else... This seems like events are useless in this case.

How are events practically used to communicate between objects? is my example the same as what is actually done in games? if not, then what do games do instead?

Comment: Why would the player control script need to know about *every* platform or enemy, bullet, etc? Does its behavior change due to a bullet that's half a screen away or even off-screen? Or does it just need to know when it *hits* one of the above? (ie. a collision event)

Comment: well, the player needs to know the position of all bullets and compute which ones hit it. Sure, it's possible to optimize that by excluding bullets which are off-screen, but that's not the point because the player still needs to know about the position of the bullet to decide whether to ignore it or not.

Comment: That sounds like it's the collision system's job, not a job the player controller should be doing. Single Responsibility Principle, and all that.

Comment: ok, so how are they connected to each other? the collision system will then have to know about all the bullets and the player, and it is basically the same problem as before because I probably don't wan't it to know about everything.

Comment: No, it just needs to know about all colliders. It doesn't need to know anything about bullets or players or platforms. So far as it's concerned, they're just a pile of shapes with positions or maybe velocities depending on how much of a physics sim you use. A bullet has a collider, but the collision system doesn't have to understand bullets to understand colliders.